# Return all groups in RegExMatch Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, regular-expressions

I have "some" generic string with some digits and others chars. I need to remove everything that is not a digit from it.

```
'a222. / --0011' -> '2220011'
```

I think this is a job to be done with Regex and I'm implementing some code with SSJS, but as far as I know only AMPScript has some [Regex funciton](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/RegExMatch.htm). Therefore, I used some [AMPScript with the SSJS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_useSSJSAMPscript.htm) to use the Regex on the string, then I will return the string to the SSJS.

If I use the pattern `'\d+'` I can get only digits, but the problem is: *RegExMatch* only returns one group (passed as arg), but I need to return all groups (all digits). How can I return a generic number of groups in RegExMatch?

Comment: I don't think so. Because in that answer there is a "pattern" to build the rowset (the "href"). In my case, I don't know what to expect, I don't have a fix string to build rowset with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is better solved by just using SSJS. AMPScript RegEx capability is not as robust as is allowed in SSJS, so it would require quite a bit of extra effort to accomplish a simple task in SSJS.

For instance, you could solve your problem in SSJS by doing below:

```js
var str = 'a222. / --0011';
var numberPattern = /\d+/g;
var res = str.match(numberPattern).join('');
```

and when you output `res`, you get `2220011`.

There is no easy way to replicate this inside of AMPScript that I am aware of, and although you should not really mix languages, this might be one of those use-cases that it makes more sense to do it this way.

You can pass the values back and forth via the [SSJS Variable functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformAMPscriptVariableFunctions.htm) to connect the two languages together.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking that Regex was not supported in SSJS. Thanks @Gortonington

Comment: Yeah almost everything not DOM or BOM related up to ECMAScript 3 in JS can be used in SSJS. I have a series on SSJS on my blog that may be useful if you have questions on SSJS: https://gortonington.com/sfmc-server-side-javascript-1-5-js-background/